# User defined test for is PartiallyRequired<SomeType>?

Tags: typescript

How can I write a function that checks that SOME fields on a type are required?

The `IFinancingModel` also has `statusDetails` which might be undefined on a valid financing so using `Required<>` is not correct.

```
export function validFinancing(
    financing: IFinancingModel | undefined,
): financing is Required<IFinancingModel> {
    return !!(
        projectFinancing && 
        projectFinancing.applicationId && 
        projectFinancing.state
    );
}
```

Comment: What does `IFinancingModel` look like? What is `PartiallyRequired<T>`?

Comment: This might be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066778/is-it-possible-to-require-only-some-specified-key-in-an-object-using-type-mappin/55067537#55067537

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Pick` to select some properties of the type and make them required and make intersect that with the original to produce the desired type:

```
type RequireSome<T, K extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, K>> & T;
interface IFinancingModel {
  applicationId?: number;
  state?: string;
  statusDetails?: string
}

export function validFinancing(
    financing: IFinancingModel | undefined,
): financing is RequireSome<IFinancingModel, 'applicationId' | 'state'> {
    return !!(
        financing && 
        financing.applicationId && 
        financing.state
    );
}
declare let o: IFinancingModel | undefined;
if (validFinancing(o)) {
  o.applicationId.toExponential // number 
  o.state.anchor; // string
  o.statusDetails.big // err can be undefined
}
```

Comment: Just curious, how could you make `RequiredSome` also remove `null` from properties? `Required<>` seems to only remove `undefined`...

Comment: @Aaron That can be done but not with `Required` we will need a more complicated type with a conditional. Let me give it a try and I'll post it

Comment: I came up with `{ [P in K]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` but seems over-complicated... (sorry to hijack answer)

Comment: @Aaron this is what I have :`type RequiredAndNotNull<T>= {
        [P in keyof T]-?:Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>
    }
    type RequireSome<T, K extends keyof T> = RequiredAndNotNull<Pick<T, K>> & T;`  if a property is `string | null | undefined` and you intersect it with `string` it will become `string` no need to do any extra picking