# Typescript type RequireSome<T, K extends keyof T> removing undefined AND null from properties

Tags: typescript, types, nullable, non-nullable, required-field

[RequireSome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55067537/4132182) type from another, very simialar question. This question is similar but it should not be a duplicate since here we want to **also remove null** as well as undefined from properties.

Maybe the name shouldn't be Require but something like NonNullable or of this kind. The goal of this type is to specify which fields from a type should not be undefined or null, and return their types without undefined and null.

```
type Question = {
    id: string;
    answer?: string | null;
    thirdProp?: number | null;
    fourthProp?: number | null;
}

// usage NonNullable<Question, 'answer' | 'thirdProp'> expect to equal
/*

type Question = {
    id: string; // no changes
    answer: string; // changed
    thirdProp: number; // changed
    fourthProp?: number | null; // no changes
}

*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplified approach that just intersects with `T` with `Required<Pick<T, K>>` with the required part basically overriding the optional properties in `T` will not work here. (Incidentally this works because `{ foo?: X } & { foo: X }` is essentially `{ foo: X }`)

To also remove nullability, we have to first create a type that removed `null` and `undefined` from a given type `T` (analogous to `Required`). Then we need to intersect the properties we want to make required and not null with the rest of the keys in `T` using the `Omit` type.

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> // not needed in ts 3.5

type RequiredAndNotNull<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>
}

type RequireAndNotNullSome<T, K extends keyof T> = 
    RequiredAndNotNull<Pick<T, K>> & Omit<T, K>

type Question = {
    id: string;
    answer?: string | null;
    thirdProp?: number | null;
    fourthProp?: number | null;
}

type T0 = RequireAndNotNullSome<Question, 'answer' | 'thirdProp'>
```

Comment: Interesting.. and working as expected :)! Just the answer prop and thirdProp are missing ?: and | null, otherwise it works correctly. `answer?: string | null` `thirdProp?: number | null`

Comment: @ZenVentzi not sure I understand your comment. Does it work as you expect it or not ? my understanding was that you wanted optionality, `null` and `undefined` removed from the listed properties, and from what I see it does

Comment: it works exactly as expected. I just wanted to point out that you've missed to add null and undefined to the answer and thirdProp, like it is in my code example above. I.e. `RequireAndNotNullSome` works as expected but with the `type Question` from your example, it doesn't make any difference because answer and thirdProp are not null and undefined anyway. Let me know if I need to explain myself more clearly!